# How to call my Android PollingService?

Tags: java, android, api, polling

I'm trying to make my android app poll the server for new messages using the example code in [this blogpost](http://it-ride.blogspot.nl/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html). I managed to copy paste everything in my project. When I run my project however, it doesn't seem to do anything.

So I've got a PollingService class in a separate file ([full code here](http://pastebin.com/v72Wrauc)) in which I tested whether it even gets called using the following constructor:

```
public class PollingService extends Service {
    public void PollingService() {
        Log.wtf("I AM ACTUALLY RUNNING", "IN THE Constructor!!!!");
    }
```

I try to call the PollingService using the following onResume from within my mainActivity:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int seconds = 3;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PollingService.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + seconds*1000, seconds*1000, pendingIntent); 
}
```

Does anybody know why the PollingService doesn't run? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the code posted, the service is declaring a void method, not a constructor and that's probably the reason why you won't see the log.

Try:

```
public class PollingService extends Service {
    public PollingService() {
        super("PollingService");
        Log.v("PollingService", "constructor");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, I fixed that. But still no sign of the message. Do you see anything wrong in my onResume method, or would you know any other reason why this wouldn't run?